# Creating script job with owner login name

Tags: sql, jobs, agent

I wonder what is reason of this error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'owner_sid', table 'msdb.dbo.sysjobs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

My script for job is as follows :

```
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'NameOfJob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'addEvent', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1,
```

....

On test enviroment all is fine but on production sth bad... some solution?

Chris

Comment: What does `SELECT SUSER_SID('sa')` do on these different environments?

Comment: when I executed SELECT SUSER_SID('sa') return 0x01 :D

Answer (score 5):

May be this is the reason

sp_add_job [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx)

[ @owner_login_name = ] 'login'
The name of the login that owns the job. login is sysname, with a default of NULL, which is interpreted as the current login name. **Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can set or change the value for @owner_login_name.** **If users who are not members of the sysadmin role set or change the value of @owner_login_name, execution of this stored procedure fails and an error is returned.**

Try to send NULL to this parameter or ask sysadmin to execute it.